# when i create a new feed,i have a problem like this Error saving Feed Duplicate key ProcessGroupDTO:b20b995a-0165-1000-0479-b059731bba5b

Tags: hive, bigdata, apache-nifi, kylo

when i create a new feed,i have a problem like this

```
Error saving Feed Duplicate key ProcessGroupDTO:b20b995a-0165-1000-0479-b059731bba5b
kylo-servers-log:
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the steps you took to lead you to this stack trace?  I'm thinking you may have improperly deleted a feed prior to attempting to create a new one with the same name.